# Windows 2003 Server doesn't start

Tags: boot, bios, windows-server-2003, acpi

My PC with Windows 2003 server has this problem: it doesn't start in normal mode, and in safe mode, it hangs-on the acpitabl.dat

I have tried to reset BIOS and disconnect all devices, without success.  I have tried to repair Windows with the install CD, but it hangs-on the beginning of the Windows setup.  I have tried disabling ACPI on setup, but it starts a boot loop.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems like CMOS battery is dying amd raid problem

Comment: Is there an UPS plugged in? Is battery still working? Tried removing non-essential hardware? Did you check hard drive integrity from say, a Linux LiveCD?

You say ACPI on setup...you mean from the BIOS, on startup? What kind of hardware is it?

Tried to spam F8 on boot, to use "Last working settings"?

Comment: there aren't an UPS plugged in.

Comment: There aren't an UPS plugged in. I think that battery is working 'cause pc keeps the setup information stored. yes, have tried turn-on without every device, it was just with keyboard plugged, but the result was the same. I have tried change the HD, I have two pcs with the same hardware, this HD worked in the another pc when I change the HDs. Yes I desable ACPI from BIOS, on startup but it starts a boot loop. this PC is a Intel Core 2 Duo E7300 2,66Ghz, 2GB RAM, MB builded by Positivo informatica (American Megatrends) I have tried spam F8 on boot, to use "Last working settings", but it hangs-on.

Answer (score -1):

1. Boot at Windows 7/8 2008/2012 CD
2. Rename %windir%\system32\drivers\update.sys
3. Boot OS 2003.

Good luck.

Comment: I didn't get very well what I have to do. I have to rename that file, but why? What name do I have to put?

Comment: @leandroteixeira `update.old` as example. And what you do not understand?